# Automatically filling custom fields with data

Tags: custom-fields, individual

Is there a way to automatically populate a custom field with data from other parts of Civi?

My use case is simple.  We have an arts organization that uses relationships to link "partners" together.  The problem is that this information is not always easy to see and requires many clicks to identify the details.

I would like to create an individual contact custom field that shows the "partners" name for each of the individuals that are linked by a household.

**Example**:

- Leslie and Shawn each have individual contact records so when I
  access Leslie's record I would like to see that there is a
  relationship with Shawn.
- It would also be great to see a household donation total in both
  records.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a thought but is it something you could do using CiviRules maybe? Setup a view only custom field and a result to set it from another field. In terms of the requirement you've stated its a very common one for us/our clients but we normally use database level triggers to denormalise data, not an extension thats released but we have toy'd with the idea of releasing one.

Answer (score 3):

Why not expose the Relationship information on the Contact Summary screen? Two ways to do this that I know of

a/ use [this extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/relationship-block) to show a block of a specified relationship type

b/ use the Contact Summary Layout editor extension but that requires resetting up the whole contact screen

Comment: That was exactly what I needed!!  Thanks!!

Comment: Any thoughts about getting the household donation totals on the summary of each relationship?

Comment: pls Accept the answer if it helped. hmm. not sure. do you mean eg looking at a householders screen, you would see eg Householder of <household name> which has donated $x

Comment: Your household donation totals question should really be its own question, and if you post it, please link to it and I'll try my best to answer it.  I can tell you what one of my clients does in this situation.  They have "spouse" relationships but no households, so this may not work for you without modification.  First - they install my "Automatic Soft Credits" extension, and configure it so that a spouse is automatically soft credited when the other spouse gives money.  Then - Extended Reports combines with Contact Summary Layout to let you post reports on the summary tab.

Comment: Also, I think the new Search Kit extension (the latest version should launch with Civi 5.32, which releases later today) should be able to generate this style of report.  I don't think it lets you put reports on the summary tab yet - but if you can generate a report with Search Kit that meets your needs, adding search kit results to the summary tab is probably coming very soon!